# Ocaml type mismatch with lists in function divide

Tags: list, types, ocaml

I'm trying to write a divide function (as part of a merge sort) that takes a list and return a couple of lists of approximately the same length.
I want to do it using the List.length() function.

My code is :

```ml
let rec transRec l1 l2 = 
  match l1, l2 with 
  | l1, [] -> l1, []
  | l1, h :: tail -> 
      if List.length l1 < List.length l2 then 
        transRec h :: l1 tail
      else 
        l1, l2
in 
transRec [] liste;;
```

I get the following error, which I do not understand, when compiling:

```bash
line 4, characters 5-26:
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'b list * 'c list
```

I do not understand why `transRec h :: l1 tail` is considered as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses around `(h :: l1)`. Without the parentheses, the expression is parsed like this:

```
(transRec h) :: (l1 tail)
```

This is because function application has high precedence in OCaml.

The compiler is telling you that the expression must be some kind of list (because of the `::` operator in the middle) but you need a pair of lists.

Answer (score 0):

While Jeffrey is quite right about the cause of the immediate error, the code demonstrated by the OP is inefficient given the way lists are handled in OCaml. Calculating the list length is O(n), and doing it within a recursive function yield O(n^2) runtime complexity.

If we take the length of the list *once* we can use a local function to split the list (roughly) in half just using a counter argument.

```
let split lst =
  let len = List.length lst in
  let rec take n lst acc =
    match lst, n with
    | [], _ | _, 0 -> List.rev acc, lst
    | x::xs, _ -> take (n - 1) xs (x :: acc) 
  in
  take (len / 2) lst []
```